# solr jump to page on select

Tags: solr

what i'd liked to do is let solr choose on what page (start entry) the result is given back depending on a document id.

imagine the following select:
localhost/solr/select?q=allMeta:Stackoverflow&rows=10

As a result i get 40 hits on 4 pages and starting at the beginning (start = 0)

Now I'd like to do the same query but using an id of a document which I know is part of the result and start at this page. For example the document is hit number 33.

localhost/solr/select?q=allMeta:Stackoverflow&rows=10&jumpToDocument=id:my_id_1

As a result i get the 40 hits on 4 pages but starting at 30.

Is this possible in any way with solr?

Comment: My new dirty approach is to do two queries. The first one with rows=99999 and fl=id returns all possible children. Then I calculate the start parameter for the second query depending on the position. I don't like this, but I don't see another way.